# Simple code does not work

Tags: android, animation

I have the following code:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
AnimationDrawable mAnim;
ImageView mouse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView mouse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mouse);
    mouse.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.eyes);
    mAnim = (AnimationDrawable)mouse.getBackground();

    Button kill = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kill);
    kill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAnim.start();
        }
    });
}
}
```

It gives an error despite it is very simple and unfortunately I cannot check logCat, because my comp  is too weak to handle an emulator. Is there any idea what is wrong with this code?

activity_main.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
            >

   <ImageView

   android:id="@+id/mouse"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:src="@drawable/u1"
    />

  <Button
   android:id="@+id/kill"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
   android:background="@drawable/playselector" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

eyes.xml (animation file):

```
<animation-list 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/u1" android:duration="15"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/u2" android:duration="15"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/u3" android:duration="15"/>

                ....
<item android:drawable="@drawable/u28" android:duration="15"/>  
</animation-list>
```

Comment: You don't need to use emulator to see logcat.. connected device works as well..

Comment: i have updated my answer. you can download a correct example.

Comment: @Hardy, My device does not support developer's mode

Comment: How is that possible.. what is your device?

Comment: @Hardy, texet X-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I figured out what the problem was, my images were too big (2000x2830).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. I've tested it.

download :

http://ubuntuone.com/1hRi0O5UMYyPoqfQj76t2i

Comment: Yes, your project works fine and it looks the same. What can be the problem then, maybe something is wrong with animation frames?

Comment: what is your name device ?

Comment: Device name: texet X-basic